# ASP.NET variable inside hyperlink / URL string

Tags: asp.net, variables

I'm trying to modify the bvcommerce order manager to link to the item that's listed so that our staff members can fill orders easier by clicking on the link, taking them to the item page instead of having to manually search it.

I wrapped an asp:hyperlink around the original asp:Label code like so:

```
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SKU">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Hyperlink NavigateUrl='/product/SKUFIELDHERE.aspx' runat="server"><asp:Label ID="SKUField" runat="server"></asp:Label></asp:Hyperlink>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Now, my problem is that I need to get the SKUField that gets populated into the Label in between '/product/' and '.aspx'

I'm not familiar with ASP.NET enough to know how to do so, and my many attempts at using <% %> and such have failed.

I've also looked at the behind, seen below:

```
Dim SKUField As Label = e.Row.FindControl("SKUField")
If SKUField IsNot Nothing Then
    SKUField.Text = lineItem.ProductSku
End If
```

So please advise me how to do so as minimally as possible, preferably without modifying the behind.

Thank you very much!

EDIT:
As seen in the comments below, I've tried now adding:

```
Dim SKULink As HyperLink = e.Row.FindControl("SKULink") 
If SKULink IsNot Nothing Then
SKULink.NavigateUrl = "products"+lineItem.ProductSku+".aspx"
End If
```

In the behind, and replaced navigateURL="SKULink" 
but now the URL is just ~/SKULink

Comment: You want to change the url dynamically ?

Comment: Is this an asp.net repeater?? If yes, try setting the url in "DataBind" event

Comment: @User2012384 Can you give me an example please?

Comment: @MairajAhmad Yes, using the same value that gets populated in the asp:label

Comment: You can find `asp:HyperLink` in code behind and set its `NavigateUrl` to your required value.

Comment: @MairajAhmad I tried that but was not exactly sure how to put the variable inbetween /product/ and .aspx

Comment: First find hyperlink in code behind like `Dim SKUField As HyperLink = e.Row.FindControl("SKULink")`; `SKUField.NavigateUrl="products"+yourvaluevariable+".aspx";`

Comment: @MairajAhmad I then get the error:
BC30288: Local variable 'SKUField' is already declared in the current block.

Comment: Oh come on change the variable name two variables with same name can't be used within a scope.

Comment: @MairajAhmad Bahah, your example had the same variable name... Let me try it with a different one.

Comment: @MairajAhmad Ok, I have:
    `Dim SKULink As HyperLink = e.Row.FindControl("SKULink")
    If SKULink IsNot Nothing Then
     SKULink.NavigateUrl = "products"+lineItem.ProductSku+".aspx"
    End If`

In the behind, and replaced navigateURL="SKULink" but now the URL is just ~/SKULink

Comment: Yeah i know i just gave the example.

Comment: Please add the code you changed in question and remove from comments.

Comment: Am I missing something? I see `VB.NET` code in the question but it is tagged `C#`.

Comment: @afsharm Apologies, must've been a misclick on a suggested tag

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue. The solution is to code it in the behind and call its ID like so in the front. Final working code to anyone who needs reference in the future:

```
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SKU">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Hyperlink ID="SKULink" runat="server"><asp:Label ID="SKUField" runat="server"></asp:Label></asp:Hyperlink>
            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

BEHIND:

```
                Dim SKUField As Label = e.Row.FindControl("SKUField")
            If SKUField IsNot Nothing Then
                SKUField.Text = lineItem.ProductSku
            End If

            Dim SKULink As HyperLink = e.Row.FindControl("SKULink")
            If SKULink IsNot Nothing Then
                SKULink.NavigateUrl = "~/product/"+lineItem.ProductSku+".aspx"
            End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Using code behind is not necessary and over complicates your code. Keep it simple, use a [HyperLinkField](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield(v=vs.110).aspx). Ditch the TemplateField.

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="DISPLAYNAME"
        DataNavigateUrlFields="SKUFIELD"
        DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/product/{0}.aspx"          
        HeaderText="SKU" />
```

Replace DISPLAYNAME with the column name (if you're binding to a data table) or the property name (if you're binding to an object). Replace SKUFIELD with the SKU column name or property name.